# How to install PHP and a SQL database on a VPS?

Tags: php, apache, command-line, installation, server

I'd like to know a basic run down of command line inputs to install Apache, PHP and a SQL database on a VPS.

I'm not sure if `sudo apt-get install php5` is enough to install php5 while getting the dependencies such as `gcc`.

I'm looking at Debian (Wheezy) as that is what a friend of mine suggested. I'm testing different websocket/wamp router solutions probably alongside if not dependent on node.js eg. socket.io or crossbar.io.

Comment: What operating system and distro do you have in mind?

Comment: I don't really have any preferences yet, I went with Debian(Wheezy) as that is what a friend of mine suggested. I'm working on testing out different websocket/wamp router solutions probably alongside if not dependent on node.js eg. socket.io or crossbar.io, the other stuff is extra assuming I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server 

sudo apt-get install apache

sudo apt-get install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli
```

There are additional instructions for installing the mysql-server:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try this. Curious if I was looking to set up a server for primary purpose of serving as a WAMP router, do I need to bother with PHP/SQL... I mean of course I imagine... anyway thank you for your response.

Comment: I must have to download these files or something, or point to a location where they can be found, every command says "unable to locate package"

Comment: what do you make of this: I tried sudo apt-get install httpd, "httpd has no installation candidate"

Comment: sorry, httpd is for centos, use sudo apt-get install apache2

Comment: a question: I installed mysql-server; is php5-mysql redundant?

Comment: I guess order doesn't matter? anyway everything is going well so far, thank you

Comment: php5-mysql adds mysql support to php, order doesnt matter too much. you need to update before anything else.